# Sharepoint like AD authentication restricting access to specific web pages

Tags: asp.net, active-directory, asp.net-membership, asp.net-roles

I have a couple of PHP applications that run over WAMP Server, and for management reasons my boss told me to migrate the into an IIS server and ASP.NET so we only have to manage one database of users, in this case the Active Directory Users Group (Windows Server 2008 R2).
So we would create a security group called Delete_Update_Stock_Toolcrib, and only the users inside said group would have access to the web page where the transaction takes place (no need for ultrasecurity, since my users a really really basic users).
So my question is, is it possible to get an automated authentication from the AD user using a .NET API?
Just like Sharepoint, where according to the security groups you are in, you can access certain parts of the information available for your departament.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could authenticate users using the built in [ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.web.security.activedirectorymembershipprovider.aspx).
Then, in ASP.Net, the concept that is the nearer of `Users Group` is `Roles`. There is a [Active Directory Roles Provider on codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28546/Active-Directory-Roles-Provider) that should allow you to map Users Group to Roles, but I never tried it.

[Here a great tutorial on the subject](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020202857/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120705-1.aspx)